# Will Factory Resetting my MacBook Pro (14", 2021) slow it down?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, restart

Will Factory Resetting my MacBook Pro (14", 2021) slow it down? I want to completely reset it and delete everything on the disk, and so will the SSD become any slower when it is reset - in other words, will it have the same performance as when it is brand new? It is a very new laptop too...

Comment: I don't want to "assume" anything, which is why I am just checking with Ask Different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word no.

The SSD will not lose any "data space" whatever that might be.

The system *might* be a little slow at first as Spotlight re-indexes everything, but that passes in a day or so depending on how much personal data you have on the Mac. But really most people don't notice a thing...

Wiping your system has **ZERO** effect on performance.